# Getting 'An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request.' Error in my MVC UserManagementController

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

When I'm executing my project and trying to access the web page `AccountSettings`, I get the error message

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Below is my code for the `UserManagementController`

```
public class UserManagementController : Controller
{
    private UserDatabaseEntities db = new UserDatabaseEntities();

    public ActionResult AccountSettings(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Login login = db.Logins.Find(id);
        if (login == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(login);
    }

    public ActionResult AccountSettings([Bind(Include = "UserID,Password")] Login login)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(login).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(login);
    }
}
```

Every other page runs fine, apart from Edit and AccountSettings, they perform similar functions however when i have user groups set up only admin will be able to access edit as the primary user creation page, and AccountSettings will be individual to user in order for them to change password on the back-end.

Here is the error message i get when trying to run the page

> [AmbiguousMatchException: The current request for action 'AccountSettings' on controller type 'UserManagementController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
>       System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult AccountSettings(System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]) on type WebSpares3.Views.UserManagementController
>       System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult AccountSettings(WebSpares3.Models.Login) on type WebSpares3.Views.UserManagementController]

Comment: Because your 2nd `AccountSettings()` method does not have `[HttpPost]` (and in future, please do not just dump all your code - just the relevant parts)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've added Http Post However it returns 'Http Error 400.0 bad request'

Comment: Then that is a entirely different question :)

Comment: You're not providing view code which triggers HTTP 400 error during POST :) I suggest you to use a viewmodel instead of `BindAttribute`.

Comment: And you return a BadRequest when `id` is `null`

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto How would i go about changing it to a viewmodel?

Comment: @OwenBennett Create a viewmodel class and put 2 properties used in `BindAttribute` (UserID, Password) as string properties. Then use model directive in view: `@model ViewModelName` & create 2 `TextBoxFor` binding to those properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message is pretty straightforward:

> The current request for action 'AccountSettings' on controller type
>   'UserManagementController' is ambiguous between the following action
>   methods

By default controller action method uses `HttpGet`, which `AccountSettings` action method definitions are ambiguous in this case due to 2 methods exist with same name and same HTTP method. Hence, the second `AccountSettings` controller requires `HttpPostAttribute` to disambiguate the request:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AccountSettings([Bind(Include = "UserID,Password")] Login login)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       // save changes & redirect
   }
   return View(login);
}
```

Note that when `AccountSettings` GET method accessed directly without providing `id` argument, it will return HTTP 400 by this block:

```
if (id == null)
{
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

It's recommended to return the view instead:

```
public ActionResult AccountSettings(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return View();
    }

    // other logic
}
```

NB: Using strongly-typed viewmodel is preferred over `BindAttribute`, so that you can control POST method easily:

**Model**

```
public class Login
{
    [Required]
    public string UserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AccountSettings(Login login)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // save changes & redirect
    }
    return View(login);
}
```

**View**

```
@model Login

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserID)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserID)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)

<input type="submit" value="Login" />
```